# Playing audio files with HTML5

Tags: jquery, html, audio

i have this code where i have three audios...i want to play them one after another after the page has loaded completely...this is happening with the following code but i can't seem to work on the delay between two audios...how do i accomplish it?

```
<audio id="my_audio">
  <source src="bark.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<audio id="my_audio2">
  <source src="roar.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<audio id="my_audio3">
  <source src="hoot.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>



    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#my_audio").get(0).play();

            $("#my_audio").bind("ended", function(){ 

                $("#my_audio2").get(0).play();

                $("#my_audio2").bind("ended", function(){ 

                $("#my_audio3").get(0).play();
            });
        });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a JSLinted, unobtrusive Javascript example demonstrating how to handle and use the ended https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events. In your particular situation, you would trigger playback of the second audio file in your ended event handler.

http://jsfiddle.net/75lb/jwyMH/

#### HTML Code

```
<ul id="playlist"><li data-ogg="http://www.lunerouge.org/sons/sf/LRWeird%201%20by%20Lionel%20Allorge.ogg">Space 1</li><li data-ogg="http://www.lunerouge.org/sons/sf/LRWeird%202%20by%20Lionel%20Allorge.ogg">Space 2</li><li data-ogg="http://www.lunerouge.org/sons/sf/LRWeird%203%20by%20Lionel%20Allorge.ogg">Space Lab</li></ul>

<button id="stop">Stop</button>
```

#### Juqery Code

```
// globals
var _player = document.getElementById("player"),
    _playlist = document.getElementById("playlist"),
    _stop = document.getElementById("stop");

// functions
function playlistItemClick(clickedElement) {
    var selected = _playlist.querySelector(".selected");
    if (selected) {
        selected.classList.remove("selected");
    }
    clickedElement.classList.add("selected");

    _player.src = clickedElement.getAttribute("data-ogg");
    _player.play();
}

function playNext() {
    var selected = _playlist.querySelector("li.selected");
    if (selected && selected.nextSibling) {
        playlistItemClick(selected.nextSibling);
    }
}

// event listeners
_stop.addEventListener("click", function () {
    _player.pause();
});
_player.addEventListener("ended", playNext);
_playlist.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (e.target && e.target.nodeName === "LI") {
        playlistItemClick(e.target);
    }
});
```

## OR

If this is your audio tag:

```
<audio id="player" src="someAudio.mp3"/>
```

then adding an event listener to it for the "ended" event will make it possible to change the source and play your next sound.

```
    var audio = document.getElementById("player");
    audio.addEventListener("ended", function() {
setTimeout(function(){
            //HERE IS YOUR CODE DO WHAT YOU WANT
        audio.src = "nextAudio.mp3";
        audio.play();
        },5000)// 5 sec delay before your nrxt function call

    });
```

Comment: i am already doing this with my current code...but i can't figure out how to wait some seconds before it starts the next audio..

Comment: and the JsLinted part i have already seen this on some other question but i can't understand the code..care to give some explanation!!